# Why is the TP4056 IC called a "linear li-ion battery charger"

Tags: battery-charging, lipo, tp4056

Being new to electrical engineering, I'm wondering why the [TP4056](http://www.tp4056.com/) IC is called a *"**linear** li-ion battery charger"* (emphasis on *linear*). Is it because the TP4056 is designed to work with a constant voltage/current input? Or is it *linear* as in "linear power supply vs switching power supply"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TP4056 uses a **[pass transistor](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/analogue_circuits/power-supply-electronics/linear-psu-series-regulator-circuit.php)** to regulate the charging voltage / current to the battery.

That pass transistor is controlled in a **linear** way, meaning a **gradual** on/off control. So the pass transistor can be fully on, fully off or any state in between (having a certain resistance).

A different type of regulator is the **switched** regulator where the pass transistor is **switched** so it can be **on** or it can be **off**. There is no state in between (like a high resistance state).

> Or is it linear as in "linear power supply vs switching power supply"?

Yes it is.

Comment: So if my understanding is correct buck/boost converter are switching regulators because of the on/off state of the transistor, right?

Answer (score 1):

It is linear as in *linear power supply*. It works by using a pass element, whose resistance is modulated so either constant current or constant voltage is supplied to the battery, charging it correctly.

**Update:**
A pass element in a linear regulator is some form of a transistor, which is operated in its "linear"/"ohmic" region, so it is neither fully conducting ("on"), nor fully off. The magic is in the biasing circuit (the rest of the linear regulator) which provides suitable voltage or current to the gate or base terminal of the transistor, so the required amount of current is *passed* from input to output.

Comment: Why do you mean by "pass element"?

Comment: I'll update my answer.